# Python webscrape not printing from all containers

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am following an online tutorial to web scrape data using python. However I am only getting the result in the last container? For example the site has 12 different products listed under 12 containers and my code only returns the data from the last container, not all 12. Can you anyone help check what I am doing wrong?

Much appreciated your help.

Thanks
Alex

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/global/nz-en/Laptops-Notebooks/SubCategory/ID-32?Tid=1567456'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()


page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

for container in containers:

    brand_description = container.a.img["title"]
    price_box = container.findAll("li",{"class":"price-current"})
    price = price_box[0].strong.text

print("brand_description:" + brand_description)
print("price:" + price)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing out the values below your loop so you only get the values those variables have after the loop is over... so the last ones. Either move your prints inside the loop or add data to a list and then print the entire list at the end.

```
for container in containers:

    brand_description = container.a.img["title"]
    price_box = container.findAll("li",{"class":"price-current"})
    price = price_box[0].strong.text

    print("brand_description:" + brand_description)
    print("price:" + price)
```

Or alternatively:

```
brand_desc = []
prices = []
price_boxes = []

for container in containers:

    brand_desc.append(container.a.img["title"])
    price_boxes.append(container.findAll("li",{"class":"price-current"}))
    prices.append(price_box[0].strong.text)

print("brand_description:" + brand_desc)
print("price:" + prices)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't express how much I wanted to thank you :)